# How can i convert a TF frozen graph .pb file to Keras .h5 (hdf5) format? (Note this is frozen graph pb and not TF saved model PB)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a TF .pb file of my TF frozen graph created using freeze_graph. I want to convert this to a keras .HDF5 model format.
Note that my original .PB was converted from a keras model. And I am on TF 1.15.

Also pls note that this is not TF Model saved PB folder, rather single PB file of frozen graph.

Comment: The [documentation](https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc) has description and code to load and use frozen model.Thanks!

Comment: My question was on how to convert the created .pb file into keras .hdf5 format. The above documentation only explains how to use it in TF session by reading the serialized graph back. This does not answer my question.